# Find() first find the index of the first letter match value and then check it the entire substring is contained in string?

Tags: python

I don’t really understand find() method. At first, I thought it was kind of like the remove() method in the sense that
remove() removes the first matching item in the list, while find() returns the index of the first letter of the substring.
But, if the entire substring does not contain in the string, it will return -1.
So is my understanding correct? find() first find the index of the first letter of the substring, and then sees if
the entire substring is contained in the string. If it does, then the index of the first letter of substring is returned.
Otherwise, -1 will be returned. If the first letter of the substring does not exist in string, -1 is returned? Or does it recursively look at each letter, if any letter does not contain in string, return -1

Comment: Your understanding is correct. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find)

Comment: Further reading of the actual implementation [here](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm). And the actual C code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a206f952668e/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. The find() method returns -1 if the entire substring has not been found in the target string, and returns the lowest index of the target string where substring has been found (the index of the first match of substring in the target string).

For example:

```
# First example (found a substring and there is only one in the target string)
In [1]: target_str = 'hello world'
In [2]: target_str.find('lo')
Out[2]: 3

# Second example (there are multiple substrings in the target string, but the start index of the first one is returned)
In [3]: target_str ='hello hello world'
In [4]: target_str.find('lo')
Out[4]: 3

# Third example (no substring has been found in the target string, so -1 is returned)
In [5]: target_str = 'bye world'
In [6]: target_str.find('lo')
Out[6]: -1
```

You can read more about the find method and its arguments in the python documentation. You can find it [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).